# How to move some file from mytheme folder to WordPress root folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've trying to change the login link /wp-admin to custom. But it should be done when the client agrees with it in Dashboard panel. I've used ACF Pro, create a checkbox in Theme Options.
There is a question: "Do you want to change the wp-admin link?" If client checked "Yes" -> click Save Changes then the new file should upload to WordPress root near wp-login.php file. My file is placed in wp-content/themes/mytheme/ folder.

Have any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you can use this plugin for doing the same https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-security-enhancer/

Comment: it will be better to get some code (function) that will do it. We trying to add this option to the Premium WordPress theme and with the plugin that you recommended we can't sell our theme in store.